# How to receive data from the environment e.g. bash

Tags: python, bash

How to read arguments from the shell, that some other program is streaming through a bash pipe? Secondly, is `print i` a proper way to stream data to the environment?

> My search lead me trough [`os`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) modules, but then:
>   The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.

However, I do not want one program to spawn the other, thej sut need to write and read from a fifo.

Comment: Can you give us more detail?  Do you just want a Python program that reads from its stdin so another program can pipe data to it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, a portable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read one line at a time from stdin and print it (you'd obviously do something else with the line, such as split() it into tokens or parse it some other way):

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Comment: And is `print` an efficient and idiomatic way to stream data from a program?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def main():
    while True:
        block = sys.stdin.read(2**20)
        if not block:
            break
        # manipulate block somehow
        sys.stdout.write(block)
```

...but that only works well if you can manipulate blocks effectively.  If you need to manipulate lines, it's better to do something like J.Z. suggested.  print is fine for line data, though I tend to lean on sys.stdout.write.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sys.stdin.readlines`.

```
➜  superlists git:(master) ✗ ls -la | python -c "import sys;print sys.stdin.readlines()"
['total 24\n', 'drwxr-xr-x   8 kracekumar  staff   272 Dec 19 00:42 .\n', 'drwxr-xr-x@  4  kracekumar  staff   136 Dec 18 01:03 ..\n', 'drwxr-xr-x  13 kracekumar  staff   442 Dec 22 10:38 .git\n', '-rw-r--r--   1 kracekumar  staff    18 Dec 18 01:10 .gitignore\n', '-rw-r--r--   1 kracekumar  staff  1463 Dec 19 00:42 function_tests.py\n', 'drwxr-xr-x  13 kracekumar  staff   442 Dec 19 00:37 lists\n', '-rw-r--r--   1 kracekumar  staff   253 Dec 18 01:03 manage.py\n', 'drwxr-xr-x  11 kracekumar  staff   374 Dec 19 00:29 superlists\n']
```

**Note:**

If the program which is piping the content to shell doesn't send `EOF`, python code will hang.